# Studentized range table - reported paper value does not match table

Tags: tukey-hsd-test, tables

I'm reading a paper on multiple comparisons (citation below). The paper reports (page 324, step 5) that we need to:

"Find the percentage point of the studentized range (SR_n) corresponding to a and n (the number of samples) and for infinite degrees of freedom."

a = alpha = 0.05

n = number of samples = 5 (in this example in the paper)

The paper then reports that this value is 2.73.

When I look up the table ([here](https://www.real-statistics.com/statistics-tables/studentized-range-q-table/), alpha=0.05, df=inf, k=5), I find 3.858

Naturally, these values are quite different and I don't think it's due to my using a table developed in the 21st century vs. the author's 1954 source.

**Question: Why is my value (3.858) different from the reported value in the paper (2.73)? How did the author find this value?**

Ryan, Thomas H. "Significance tests for multiple comparison of proportions, variances, and other statistics." Psychological bulletin 57.4 (1960): 318-328.

Comment: Not sure if this is any help but the qtukey() function in R seems to agree with the table you link to.

Comment: Thanks @mdewey, that's a great place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you and they disagree by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$. If you look at the table rows with $k=2$, they have the familiar 1.96.

R gives

```
> round(qtukey(.95,5:2,Inf),2)
[1] 3.86 3.63 3.31 2.77
> round(qtukey(.95,5:2,Inf)/sqrt(2),2)
[1] 2.73 2.57 2.34 1.96
```

where the 3.858 matches what you found in the reference table, and the second row matches the studentized ranges in the table in the paper

I think footnote 5 may be explaining the factor of $\sqrt{2}$?